# Linking Angular 4 and OpenLayers 4

Tags: angular, openlayers

I have two components:

- map
- controls

I want the buttons on the controls component to interact with the map. Example adding an interaction to the map:

Controls component:

- HTML: `<button (click)="add_a_place()" type="button">Add a place</button>`
- JS: `add_a_place() {map.addInteraction(draw_interaction)}`

Map component:

- JS:

`var draw_interaction =  new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: vector_source,
            type: "Point"
     });
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [vector_layer],
      view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
    });`

Any idea how this could/should be done?

I am using:

- Angular 4.0.0
- OpenLayers 4.1.1

Comment: Check out this example which demonstrates creating Custom Controls on the map http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html?q=control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've done to achieve this:

Using component interaction (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), I included `controlComponent` inside `mapComponent`. Using an `eventEmitter`, I tell the `mapComponent` what to do (managing the map inside the `MapComponent` allows you to use different `controlComponent`).

MapComponent (HTML) :

```
<app-control (add_a_place)="add_a_place($event)"> </app-control>
```

MapComponent (TS) :

```
add_a_place(event) {
 var draw_interaction =  new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: vector_source,
        type: "Point"
 });
   var map = new ol.Map({
   target: "map",
   layers: [vector_layer],
   view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
      })
   });
   map.addInteraction(draw_interaction);
}
```

Controls component (HTML):

```
<button (click)="sendInfo()" type="button">Add a place</button>
```

JS:

```
export class VoterComponent {
// change 'any' to the desired type, this is optional
@Output() add_a_place= new EventEmitter<any>();

sendInfo() {
    // this will call MapComponent's add_a_place function
    this.add_a_place.emit('you can pass an argument of type "any" to the mapComponent, depending on the eventEmitter above, but this is optional');
}
```

Don't hesitate if you have questions or if I wasn't clear.

This is the logic for inclusion of 'angular-made' controls, but you can also add openlayers's controls see: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html

But you could also include `MapComponent` inside an `overlayComponent` which includes controls, in which case you would have to reverse the component interaction logic (just ignore this if it isn't clear).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to start from zero with Angular5 ans OpenLayers4, there is a mature project called [IGO2-lib](https://github.com/infra-geo-ouverte/igo2) which is based on `Angular 5.x`, `NodeJS`, `OpenLayers 4.x` and `Material Design`. [IGO2](http://igouverte.org/english/) is also a complete framework.

1. Clone repository using: `git clone https://github.com/infra-geo-ouverte/igo2-lib.git`
2. Deploy in cd igo2-lib/ and install from: `npm install`
3. Start form: `npm start`
4. Open your browser at http://localhost:4200/

Here it is a live demo from [IGO2](http://igouverte.org/english/): https://geoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/igo2/apercu-qc/